# How to change the tab pane style

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I use the default JavaFX tab pane layout

[image]

I want to display new tabs below the old ones. I don't want to display the default context menu to select which tab to display. Are there any options to change this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try this....change it according your need.this is default css for tab pane and their layout... i used it and work sucessfully

```
.tab-pane 
{
-fx-skin: "com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TabPaneSkin";
/* -fx-tab-min-width: 4.583em;  55 */
/* -fx-tab-max-width: 4.583em; 55 */
-fx-tab-min-height: 2em; /* 24 */
-fx-tab-max-height: 2em; /* 24 */
}
.tab .tab-label 
{
-fx-skin: "com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabelSkin";
-fx-background-color: transparent;    
-fx-alignment: CENTER;
-fx-text-fill: -fx-text-base-color;
}
/*
.tab *.tab-label Text {
-fx-effect: dropshadow(two-pass-box , rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 1, 0.0 , 0, 1);
}*/
.tab-content-area 
{
-fx-background-color: -fx-control-inner-background;
-fx-padding: 0.0em; /* 0 */
/* -fx-opacity: -fx-disabled-opacity;*/
}
.tab 
{
/* This is how it is done in Button, but the -1 inset caused a white line  */
/* to appear beneath the tab, which looks bad, so it's taken out below.    */
/*    -fx-background-color: -fx-shadow-highlight-color, -fx-tab-border-color, -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color;
-fx-background-radius: 5 5 0 0, 5 5 0 0, 4 4 0 0, 3 3 0 0;
-fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0, 0, 1, 2;*/
-fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2;
-fx-background-radius: 5 5 0 0, 4 4 0 0, 3 3 0 0;
-fx-padding: 0.083333em 0.5em 0.083333em 0.5em; /* 1 6 1 6 */
/*    -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-base-color;*/
}
.tab:top 
{
-fx-background-color: -fx-tab-border-color, -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color;
}
.tab:right 
{
-fx-background-color: -fx-tab-border-color, -fx-inner-border-bottomup, -fx-body-color-bottomup;
}
.tab:bottom 
{
-fx-background-color: -fx-tab-border-color, -fx-inner-border-bottomup, -fx-body-color-bottomup;
}
.tab:left 
{
-fx-background-color: -fx-tab-border-color, -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color;
}
.tab:hover 
{
-fx-color: -fx-hover-base;
}
.tab:selected 
{
/*    -fx-background-color: white;*/
/*    -fx-background-color: -fx-tab-border-color, -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color;
-fx-background-radius: 5 5 0 0, 4 4 0 0, 3 3 0 0;
-fx-background-insets: 0, 1 1 0 1, 2 2 0 2;*/
-fx-background-color: -fx-tab-border-color, -fx-control-inner-background;
-fx-background-insets: 0, 1 1 0 1;
-fx-background-radius: 5 5 0 0, 4 4 0 0;
}
.tab:disabled 
{
-fx-opacity: -fx-disabled-opacity;
}
.tab:disabled:hover 
{
-fx-color: -fx-base;
-fx-opacity: -fx-disabled-opacity;
}
.tab-pane *.tab-header-background 
{
-fx-background-color: -fx-outer-border, -fx-inner-border, derive(-fx-color, -20%);
-fx-effect: innershadow(two-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 4, 0.0 , 0 , 0);
}
/*.tab-pane *.tab-header-area {*/
/* I would like to use -fx-tab-border-color here, but for some reason it */
/* just isn't the correct color, even though it works in :top above */
/*    -fx-background-color: -fx-tab-border-color, lightgray;*/
/*}*/
.tab-pane:top *.tab-header-area 
{
-fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
-fx-padding: 0.416667em 0.166667em 0.0em 0.833em; /* 5 2 0 10 */
}
.tab-pane:bottom *.tab-header-area 
{
-fx-background-insets: 0, 1 0 0 0;
-fx-padding: 0 0.166667em 0.416667em 0.833em; /* 0 2 5 0 */
}
.tab-pane:left *.tab-header-area 
{
-fx-background-insets: 0, 0 1 0 0;
-fx-padding: 0.833em 0.0em 0.166667em 0.416667em; /* 10 0 2 5 */
}
.tab-pane:right *.tab-header-area 
{
-fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 0 1;
-fx-padding: 0.833em 0.416667em 0.166667em 0.0em; /* 10 5 2 0 */
}
.tab-pane .headers-region 
{
-fx-effect: dropshadow(two-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 4, 0.0 , 0, 0);
}
/* TODO: scaling the shape seems to make it way too large */
.tab-close-button 
{
-fx-background-color: -fx-mark-color;
-fx-shape: "M 0,0 H1 L 4,3 7,0 H8 V1 L 5,4 8,7 V8 H7 L 4,5 1,8 H0 V7 L 3,4 0,1 Z";
-fx-scale-shape: false;
-fx-effect: dropshadow(two-pass-box , rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 1, 0.0 , 0, 1);
}
.tab-close-button:hover 
{
-fx-background-color: derive(-fx-mark-color, -30%);
}
/* CONTROL BUTTONS */
.control-buttons-tab 
{
-fx-background-color: -fx-tab-border-color, -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color;
-fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2;
-fx-background-radius: 5 5 0 0, 4 4 0 0, 3 3 0 0;
-fx-padding: 0.083333em 0.25em 0.083333em 0.25em; /* 1 3 1 3 */
}
.tab-down-button 
{
-fx-background-color: transparent;
-fx-padding: 0.0em 0.416667em 0.0em 0.416667em; /* 0 5 0 5 */
}
.tab-down-button:hover 
{
-fx-background-color: -fx-body-color;
-fx-color: -fx-hover-base;
}
.tab-down-button .arrow 
{
-fx-background-color: -fx-mark-highlight-color, -fx-mark-color;
-fx-background-insets: 1 0 -1 0, 0;
-fx-padding: 0.238083em 0.416667em 0.238083em 0.416667em; /* 2.857 5 2.857 5 */
-fx-shape: "M 0 0 H 7 L 3.5 4 z";
}
/* FLOATING TABS CUSTOMISATION */
.tab-pane.floating *.tab-header-background {
-fx-background-color: null;
}
.tab-pane.floating *.tab-header-area 
{
-fx-background-color: null;
}
.tab-pane.floating *.tab-content-area 
{
-fx-background-color: -fx-tab-border-color, -fx-control-inner-background;
-fx-background-insets: 0, 1;
-fx-background-radius: 5, 4;
}
.tab-pane.floating *.tab 
{
-fx-background-color: -fx-tab-border-color, -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color;
-fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2;
-fx-background-radius: 5 5 0 0, 4 4 0 0, 3 3 0 0;
}
.tab-pane.floating *.tab:selected 
{
-fx-background-color: -fx-tab-border-color, -fx-control-inner-background;
-fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0, 1 1 -1 1;
-fx-background-radius: 5 5 0 0, 4 4 0 0;
}
/*.tab-pane:floating *.control-buttons-tab 
{
-fx-padding: 0.083333em 0.25em 0.083333em 0.25em;
-fx-background-color: -fx-tab-border-color, -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color;
-fx-background-radius: 5 5 0 0, 4 4 0 0, 3 3 0 0;
-fx-background-insets: 0, 1 1 0 1, 2 2 0 2;
}*/
```

Comment: Do you have an example of usage? The given styles disable the hover and change the appearance, but the tabs are not displayed in multiple rows as the OP asked, nor is the default dropdown menu hidden (that contains the overflow when too many tabs are displayed in a row to all be visible).

Comment: @BrentFoust which version of Javafx you are using?  This is working with javafx 2.2. in case of javafx 8, the css will be different according the theme.

Comment: I'm using JavaFX 8. Thanks for your comment. Which of your CSS rules gives the multiple rows of Tabs?