# Tab background in FXML

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I can set the background of the entire window through CSS with .background, but when I use a TabPane, it's white background overrides the background and covers it with white. How can I apply the same background to the tab menu and it's content?

Comment: Try to set the background of TabPane (and maybe its subnodes) to transparent. Search the SO for setting background color of components and refer to the official CSS Reference Guide.

Comment: try this...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091605/how-to-change-the-tab-pane-style